# ClearCase in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: clearcase, visual-studio-2015

Is there any workaround to get Rational ClearCase running in VS2015 RC? It looks like no plugin is available yet. Can I somehow use the plugin from VS2013?

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed by user5337760 worked perfectly for me.

1. In ccvsisearchtoolwin_VS2013.reg and reg_VS2013.bat, globally change all the 12.0 instances to 14.0.  (I don't use the Remote Client, so these 2 files are the only ones I needed.)
2. Check the environment variables in reg_VS2013.bat to be sure they match your setup.
3. Run reg_VS2013.bat.

Comment: I had to open a command prompt as an Administrator and change the current directory, but once I did that, everything worked as expected. I'm even running an older version of Clear Case (7.1.1.5). Undo checkout doesn't work within VS but that never did on earlier versions either.

Comment: Worked great for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.almtoolbox.com/blog/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-integration-with-clearcase, Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 is integrated with ClearCase as of release 8.0.1.10.

The same site has also a non-official Visual Studio integration with ClearCase 9.

Answer (score 1):

First, apply the the latest fix pack for your ClearCase Client version. Support for VS2015 may already be included.

If not, start with the approach given by IBM for VS2013 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24036865

Before executing the scripts though, be sure to replace all references to VS2013 ("12.0") with ("14.0") in the batch and registry scripts provided.

Also, since you're probably using a 64-bit system, be sure to specify "Program Files (x86)" where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I somehow use the plugin from VS2013?

You can try, but it isn't supported officially.
I don't know of a compatible ClearCase plugin for now.

Answer (score 0):

Official support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 was introduced in ClearCase 8.0.1.10 as noted in the "[What's New](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045000)" page.