# ClearCase Integration for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, clearcase, visual-studio-2017

Does anyone know if there's a way to integrate clearcase 8.0.1.06 into visual studio 2017? I tried the registry hack detailed in this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069163/clearcase-in-visual-studio-2015/34322044#34322044) and also uninstalling and reinstalling clearcase after installing VS2017 but nothing seems to work. If there is no support for VS2017 currently, does anyone know how long it usually takes before clearcase is supported? Thank you.

Edit: I [posted the same question](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/372947/clearcase-integration-for-visual-studio-2017/) on the IBM dev forum and someone responded that the ClearCase devs are working on support but it won't be available for a quarter or two.

Comment: Why would anyone be using something other than Subversion or Git?  The lack of support should tell you something.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too deeply integrated into the project to change :(

Comment: Time to migrate.  Honestly, you might be the last Clear Case customer Rational/IBM has.  You'll migrate faster than Microsoft will provide support.

Comment: @duffymo Large companies have a hard time changing their processes; hundreds or thousands of people have to be trained, hundreds or thousands of scripts have to be re-written, if you have legal requirements for reviewing and archiving you have to re-define, review and get approval for those processes as well. That may be lamentable but this lock-in concerns quite a few well-paying customers. And then it's not as if other systems din't have their own set of problems.

Comment: Okay, then don’t. Stay with antiquated stuff. I work for a Dow company. I know what big means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the "[Collaborate on Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/collaborate/)" Visual Studio 2017 page, the focus is now on Git.
As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789126/clearcase-integration-for-visual-studio-2017/43792376?noredirect=1#comment102134110_43792376) by [Peter A. Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150802/peter-a-schneider), there is a [IBM Rational ClearCase integration with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/integrate-ibm-rational-clearcase-microsoft-visual-studio-2017). The [installation instruction](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/vs2017/Installation_Instructions_VS2017.pdf), though, might not work fully.

That being said, trying to integrate such an obsolete source control system such as ClearCase is counter-productive. IBM is working on integration its successor RTC (Rational Team Concert) [with RTC 6.0.4](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/237214/rational-team-concert-plugin-support-for-visual-studio-2017).

That being said, you can still try and see if the extension "
[VS Code ClearCase](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OpenNingia.vscode-clearcase)" works for you. It is however for [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), *not* for VS 2017.

Comment: A few corrections:(1) ClearCase is not obsolete and is increasing development investment as part of the partnership between IBM and HCL Technologies.  (2)  RTC is not the successor to ClearCase.  There's a reason IBM has continued to sell and support both products.  (3)  ClearCase does not yet support an integration with VS 2017 but it is being actively worked on.  Stay tuned...

Comment: IBM's ClearCase plugin is available [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/integrate-ibm-rational-clearcase-microsoft-visual-studio-2017). I have not tried it yet.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back. One issue I remember from one plugin was that it affected the project files in a way which bothered people without the plugin.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thank you. I will include your report in the answer as well.

Comment: OK, the installation is a joke: The [instructions](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/vs2017/Installation_Instructions_VS2017.pdf) ask you to manually change paths in configuration files, including paths which do not have an equivalent in my specific installation location. It did not work properly after I installed it, whether due to an editing error or for other reasons I do not know. VS opened an error dialog pointing to an xml trouble log file again in a location which did not exist. Simply using CC on the side appears to be easier.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider That has been often my experience: using cleartool in console while working in an IDE.